# Bundle Identifier: setup for new project with IOS App+Framework+Today Extension

Tags: ios, swift, ios-app-extension, bundle-identifier

I'm in the process of starting to develop an IOS/Swift App with a Framework to share common logic with a Today Widget and I have some questions about the Bundle Identifier:

1. If I choose something as *org.whateverIwant.TestBundleID* for the App, should whateverIwant.org really exist or is it simply a unique identifier?
2. If I later add an a Cocoa Touch custom Framework to the project, it asks me for a Product Name (TestBundleIDFramework) and then it appends by default the product name to *org.whateverIwant* without *TestBundleID*. Instead, if I add a Target for a Today Extension it appends the Product Name (TestBundleIDExtension) to *org.whateverIwant.TestBundleID*. Given the fact that all the three parts (App, Today Extension and Framework) are part of the same app that I'll upload to the store, is this way of using BundleIDs correct? Should also the Framework be under *org.whateverIwant.TestBundleID*, such as *org.whateverIwant.TestBundleID.TestBundleIDFramework* as for the Today Extension?
3. Is it extremely important to chose the right Bundle ID at the beginning of the project (consider that I still have no developer account, I'll pay for it as soon as I see that I'm able to build the app I'd like to) or can it be changed without hassle later on?

An brief OT question: there is a Version field for each target, what is the one that Apple looks at when determining if the uploaded bundle (App+Extension+Framework) has been updated to a new version?

Comment: As far as I know…

The bundle identifier is just a unique id, but it is a way of identifying you, so making it something that can be traced to you is helpful.

Bundle Ids also help bundle your application(s) together, this in the form of 'All the applications that belong to' as well as 'all the components of this application'.

Generally your application id will be com.organisation.application.

Finally, it's possible to change the ids, but not once they are published in a store, so semi-important.

I think that helps, if not, I'll try to elaborate.

Comment: @ChrisChinchilla is bundle id for framework should be `com.organisation.application.FrameworkName` or `com.organisation.FrameworkName` or it doesn't matter at all?

Answer (score 0):

1. No. It is simply an unique indentifier.
2. You mentioned three: "App+Extension+Framework" I think only the App's bundle ID matters because you are going to submit the App. The Extension and Framework are just part of the App, theirs bundle IDs are internal which means nothing to App store.
3. You can change the bundle ID as long as you haven't submitted your App to App Store.

OT Question: App Store only cares about your App's bundle ID and version number.